# Is there any memory leak in following snippet of code?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimage, memory-leaks

'countdown' is an uimageview property as defined below:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *countDown;

countDown.image=  [[[UIImage alloc] 
      initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
      pathForResource:@"backgroundimage" ofType:@"png"]]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be.

If you find this from the Leaks Instrument it is showing you where the leaked object is **created** not where it is leaking.

So, while it looks okay, you are passing an autoreleased object to a property and properties usually manage their memory well enough, you are doing something else with that image that is causing it to not be released.

You could have forgotten to release it in a dealloc, or used it without realising that you have a strong reference to it.

What you need to do is try and follow the lifetime of that image to see where you are retaining it that doesn't have a release.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what is **countDown** object, and whether you are releasing property **image** in **dealloc()** method of the class which countDown is an object of.

EDIT: After seeing your question edit..

No memory leaks, if you are releasing countDown correctly.